# Can't insert message after TouchID authentication

Tags: ios, swift, imessage-extension

So I'm playing around a bit with iMessage apps, and have hit a weird issue. I want to try and use TouchID authentication inside of iMessage, and am able to pop the TouchID alert fine from the iMessage app. However, when I go to insert a message showing the result of TouchID, it won't insert the message for me. Here's the relevant code:

```
@IBAction func authenticateTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let context = LAContext()
    var wasSuccessful = false
    self.group.enter()
    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Testing authentication") { (successful, _) in

        wasSuccessful = successful
        self.group.leave()
    }

    self.group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.sendResult(wasSuccessful)
    }
}

@IBAction func sendMessageTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    sendResult(true)
}

func sendResult(_ successful: Bool) {
    guard let conversation = self.activeConversation else { fatalError("expected conversation") }

    var components = URLComponents()
    components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "successful", value: successful.description)]

    let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
    layout.image = UIImage(named: "green_checkmark")
    layout.caption = "Authentication Result"

    let message = MSMessage(session: conversation.selectedMessage?.session ?? MSSession())
    message.url = components.url!
    message.layout = layout

    print("queryParts: \(String(describing: components.queryItems))")
    print("message: \(message)")
    print("activeConversation: \(String(describing: conversation))")

    conversation.insert(message) {
        (error) in

        print("in completion handler")
        print(error ?? "no error")
    }
}
```

When `authenticateTapped` is triggered, the TouchID prompt shows, I successfully authenticate, and then see every log message inside of the `sendResult` message, except for any of the ones in the completion handler of the `insert` method.

The weird thing is, when the `sendMessageTapped` method is fired, everything works as expected. Does anyone know what's going on here, and why I can't seem to insert a message after I successfully authenticate using TouchID?

The only thing I can think of that's different between the two is that the view controller is disappearing when the TouchID prompt comes up, however, if that were the cause, I would expect none of my `print` statements would show up in the console, when everyone does except those in the completion handler?

Edit: I've done a bit more digging. When presenting the Touch ID authentication in `compact` mode, your view controller resigns active. When presenting in `expanded` mode, it stays active, allowing you to insert the message.

Does anyone know if resigning active when presenting the Touch ID alert is a bug or intended behavior?